# Why can I ping the Ip of a different Network Interface of my server?

Tags: networking, debian, ip, ping, network-interface

I have my local Machine (`10.0.0.2/16`) directly connected to the `eth4` network interface of my server.
The connection works as expected and I can traceroute the ip of `eth4`, namely `10.0.0.1`.
However, **I can also traceroute** the ip `10.1.0.23` of **the other interface** (`eth5`), even though it is on the wrong subnet!

In the following you see the settings of my local machine and my server.

## On my local Machine (Arch Linux)

Output of `ip addr`:

```
....
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 3c:97:0e:8a:a1:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.2/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global enp0s25
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::7a0b:adb3:2eef:a3a8/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
....
```

### Traceroutes

```
% sudo traceroute -I 10.0.0.1
traceroute to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)  0.184 ms  0.170 ms  0.163 ms

% sudo traceroute -I 10.1.0.23
traceroute to 10.1.0.23 (10.1.0.23), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.1.0.23 (10.1.0.23)  0.240 ms  0.169 ms  0.166 ms
```

## On Server (Debian)

My `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#iface eth5 inet dhcp
auto eth5
allow-hotplug eth5
iface eth5 inet static
    address 10.1.0.23 
    netmask 255.255.0.0  
    gateway 10.1.0.1


## Automatically load eth4 interface at boot 
auto eth4  
allow-hotplug eth4
# Configure network interface at eth4 
iface eth4 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1 
    netmask 255.255.0.0  
    gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...
6: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:a2:0a:e8:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/16 brd 10.0.255.255 scope global eth4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::208:a2ff:fe0a:e886/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: eth5: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:08:a2:0a:e8:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.0.23/16 brd 10.1.255.255 scope global eth5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ip route`:

```
default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth5 
10.0.0.0/16 dev eth4  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1 
10.1.0.0/16 dev eth5  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.1.0.23
```

Comment: The routing table on your local arch machine matters more than the routing table on your server, you should look at it, and show us too.

Comment: I struggled trying to decide whether to flag this as off-topic.  In the future, please make it more clear why questions like this are about programming rather than system administration.  In my experience though I do find that I'm puzzled over issues like what is locally received more with my network programming hat on than with my sysadmin hat on, so I proposed an answer.

Comment: @SamHartman: Sorry, my fault. I'm pretty new to stackoverflow and didn't know that it's soleley for explicitly programming related issues. So would [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) be the right place for this kind of question or rather [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you expect this behavior.  As you can see from your Debian server's routing tables, it knows how to route packets to your arch linux machine, so it can respond if it wants to.
I can see two likely questions you might be having:

- Why does it choose to respond?

You haven't given us your firewall rules, or told us whether your server has ip_forwarding enabled.  Even without IP forwarding enabled, Linux will see a locally received packet for any of its local addresses as an INPUT packet (in terms of iptables and access control decisions), not a forwarded packet.  So it will respond even if forwarding is disabled.
If you don't want this behavior you could add an iptables rule to the INPUT chain to drop the packet being received on the server.

- Why is there only one hop in the traceroute

You might expect that in order to respond the packet would need to traverse (be forwarded) and so you would get two hops in your traceroute one for eth4 and one for eth5.  However, as mentioned above, any locally received ppacket will be treated as input if it matches one of the local IPs.  Your arch linux box presumably uses the Debian server as its default route.  So, it sends a packet with the Debian server's MAC address, hoping the Debian server will forward it.  That makes it a locally received packet at the ethernet level on the Debian serevr.  The server then cehcks teh IP address, finds it is local, doesn't care it's for another ethernet and locally receives it at the IP layer.
If you don't want that behavior, fix in firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (even though as you noted above it's off-topic).

Comment: I just was really surprised that as you said "Linux will see a locally received packet for any of its local addresses as an INPUT packet". I would have expected that each incoming package only is processed **iff** it fits the subnet of the Network interface it was received on, or a route is set for it.

Comment: @Hermilton  If my answer answers your question, please accept it.  See, there *is* an implicit route to every local interface of the system.  Routes aren't from a source to a destination; they are just to a destination, and a system has an implicit route to all its local addresses.